# edited rc-sysinit.conf system won't boot

Tags: runlevel

I have modified the `DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL` from 2 (graphical interface) to 1 in `rc-sysinit.conf`, to install drivers for GPU. After choosing either default or recovery mode, I see just black screen. Any ideas, what went wrong and how to get into text interface or at least revert the changes?

Any help will be much appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 as a second system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot using a live CD / USB
2. Mount partition of the installed Ubuntu
3. Change back `DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2` in `rc-sysinit.conf`
4. Reboot.

Now, it should get back as it was. To install the graphic driver (no need to do such thing):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to tty1 terminal
2. Stop X server

   ```
   sudo stop lightdm
   ```
3. Install needed driver
4. Then reboot

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```